# CSS three columns of fixed width and same hight

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a container that has 3 columns. Each column has a fixed width that I've specified. Each column must span the entire height of the container.

The problem I'm having is that the columns shift up/down depending on the content of the columns. Check http://jsfiddle.net/bhw44w7q/ to see what I mean. What's the best way to get this right?

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">left left left left left</div>
    <div id="middle">middle middle middle middle middle</div>    
    <div id="right">right right right right right</div>
</div>

#container {
    height: 500px;
    width: 750px;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
}
#left {
    background-color: #fcc;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
}
#middle {
    background-color: #cfc;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
}
#right {
    background-color: #ccf;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 590px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for `vertical-align`(applies to inline-level and `table-cell` elements) is `baseline`(`baseline` of the previous element), this is why you are experiencing that.

You could use `vertical-align: top` along with `display: inline-block` to prevent this.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhw44w7q/2/)**

```css
#container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 750px;
  background-color: black;
}
#left {
  background-color: #fcc;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
}
#middle {
  background-color: #cfc;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
}
#right {
  background-color: #ccf;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 590px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">left left left left left</div>
  <div id="middle">middle middle middle middle middle</div>
  <div id="right">right right right right right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with CSS, but there are a few JavaScript solutions to solve this problem, like this one: https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height

Comment: Looks like an awesome plugin, but I'm trying to avoid jQuery for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `vertical-align: top;` to each div solved the problem for me. http://jsfiddle.net/bhw44w7q/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the css `float` property: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdy1L6qb/)

```
#container {
    height: 500px;
    width: 750px;
    background-color: black;
}
#left {
    background-color: #fcc;
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
}
#middle {
    background-color: #cfc;
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
}
#right {
    background-color: #ccf;
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 590px;
}
```